# running MonoGame on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, mono

I'm trying to get a MonoGame project working on my Pi.

I've done the following:

sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
sudo apt-get install libmonogame-cil-dev monodevelop-monogame

Then I launched MonoDevelop and created a new Solution/Project: MonoGame Linux Application

Without making any code or configuration changes, the game builds ok, but when I try to run it I get a System.NullReferenceException at OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode.get_Default()

By default, the Build Configuration is set to Default|x86 which seems a little weird since I'm targeting the Pi, which is obviously not x86. The only options I see are Debug|x86, Release|x86 or Any CPU (all of which I've tried.)

Am I using the wrong project type (Linux)?
Or am I missing a library (OpenTK maybe?)
Or is there something special I need to do in the Build Configuration?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to make some tweaks to OpenTK to get it working on the Pi. I did have a blog post on the subject but after a site hack I lost it but web archive has it

http://web.archive.org/web/20121203091113/http://infinitespace-studios.co.uk/2012/11/14/monogame-on-the-raspberry-pi/

bascially, you need to hack your own version of GLES (because by default it doesn't support hardware acceleration in X11)

then you need to hack OpenTK... (my fork github.com/dellis1972/opentk)
then you need to hack monogame....

My code changes are in https://github.com/dellis1972/MonoGame/tree/pi but it is way way out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This may be more work than I'm ready for, but I'm going to give it a try.